# How can I get history of "OPTIMIZE TABLE xxxxx" executions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, information-schema

We know "OPTIMIZE TABLE xxxx" or "ANALYZE TABLE xxxx" is helpful in defragmentation of MySQL Tables. Is there any way we can have a visibility on what tables this OPTIMIZE/ANALYZE TABLE statment was performed and when ?

I know, when we OPTIMIZE a table, MySQL first creates a TEMPORARY table, and then drops the Orig table, then replaces the TEMP as Orig table. Will it be helpful in tracking the OPTIMIZE TABLE statement history ? If so, how?

Appriciate if there any other methods to find out this.

Thanks in advance!!

I have tried the below, it is not really that helpful.

```
SELECT *, ROUND(data_length/1024/1024) AS data_length_mb, ROUND(data_free/1024/1024) AS data_free_mb
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'myDB'
ORDER BY data_free_mb DESC ;
```

Looking at the TABLES created_date is not helping. Because it gives the newly created tables as well.

Comment: General Query Log (if enabled) stores complete history of all received queries. You may enable it.. but remember that it spends a lot of resources. Disable it when logging not needed, and do not forget to truncate log file.

Comment: @akina, reading the log file seems time-consuming and a little problematic. I was wondering if those stats can be available either in information_schema or performance_schema tables. It will be easier to query them. Do you know any such things, if we have?

Comment: AFAIR there is no built-in solution for your task. You may try to search for custom UDF which implements such selective logging. But I doubt that you will succeed..